# how to remove the blue background on the "active" NavDropdown.Item while using LinkContainer?

Tags: react-bootstrap

While using `LinkContainer` in react-bootstrap, the "*active*" `<NavDropdown.Item />` gets *`blue`* as it's *`background-color`*.
for.e.g:

```
<NavDropdown>
    <LinkContainer to="/profile">
     <NavDropdown.Item>profile</NavDropdown.Item>
    </LinkContainer>
    <LinkContainer to="/">
     <NavDropdown.Item>
      logout
     </NavDropdown.Item>
    </LinkContainer>
</NavDropdown>
```

How do I remove it and replace it with my own color ?

I tried doing this :

```
a .active.dropdown-item {
  background-color: white
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have no experience with React-Bootstrap but I guess it's getting the pseudo-class `:active`.

So you have to do something like:

```
a:active {
  background-color: white
}
```

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_active.asp

Comment: Thanks. Though it is not the exact answer, but this concept helped me to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Solution(let's assume that we want to add green as the background):

1. For the moment you click the link i.e to show the active link:-

   a.dropdown-item:active{
   background-color: green;
   }
2. For the color to stay on the active NavDropdown.Item:

   a.active.dropdown-item {
   background-color: green;
   }
   OR

   you could add `activeStyle` prop in the `LinkContainer`

   <LinkContainer
   to="/profile"
   activeStyle={{
   backgroundColor: "green",
   }} />